# How to layer two JPanels and have them fill the entire JFrame in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

I'm making a board game in Java, and I am trying to render the board itself in JPanel. The way I'm trying to do this is by inserting a image of the board (which is represented by a JLabel) and a grid (which is also represented by a JPanel). The idea is for each grid square to correspond to the squares on the image of the board.

Here is what it currently looks like

[image: Here is what it currently looks like.]

As you can see, it's not aligning correctly. Here is the code I tried to accomplish this:

```
public class BoardImage {
    ImagePanel test = new ImagePanel();
    GridPanel grid = new GridPanel();

    public void returnBoardPanel() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JPanel Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel image = new JLabel();
        image = test.createImage();
        image.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(image);
        frame.add(grid.paintMe());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] agrs) {
        BoardImage test = new BoardImage();
        test.returnBoardPanel();
    }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    public JLabel createImage() {
        JLabel temp = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getImage("/boardEdit.jpeg"));
        temp.setIcon(icon);
        temp.setBounds(0, 0, 552, 575); //needed in order for 24x25 to work
        return temp;
    }

    public Image getImage(String filePath) {
        int width, height;
        Image tempImage = null;
        try {
            /* Loads the image, and assigns it to the tempImage var */
            URL imagePath = BoardImage.class.getResource(filePath);
            tempImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagePath);
        }
        catch(Exception e){ //if the filePath does not exist, or something else messed up
            System.err.println("We were not able to load the requested image form the given filePath: " + "\n" + filePath);
        }
        return tempImage;
    }
}

class GridPanel extends JPanel{
    private JLabel[][] grid;

    public GridPanel paintMe(){
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 552, 575); //needed in order for 24x25 to work
        this.fillGrid();
        this.setOpaque(false);
        return this;
    }

    public void fillGrid() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(24, 25));

        grid = new JLabel[24][25];

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = new JLabel();
                grid[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));//keep this until it works
                grid[i][j].setOpaque(false);
                this.add(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I've found online, and on SO, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your layering appears to be working, and all it seems that you have to do is juggle your numbers a bit so that your grids line up. This is something *you* will need to work on, as I doubt anyone here wants to do this for you. Note that for my money, I wouldn't layer JPanels, but rather draw the image in a single JPanel's paintComponent method along with the grid.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Those are great points. OTOH if the squares in the board game are anything like the places in a chess board, it might make sense to carve the image up and use each sub-image as the icon for a `JButton` as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556).

Comment: I'm looking into BufferedImages now, it looks like that's exactly what I need. Thank you!